# PHP to send smtp emails with pear mail module

Tags: pear, php

Initially i was sending emails through mail() function, but they always get caught in the spam folder, so now i want to send them using SMTP using PHP PEAR, but i am getting some errors.

in the functions.php i have the email function like;

```
function send_mail($from,$to,$subject,$body)
{
    // Setting up the SMTP setting
    $smtp_info["host"] = "smtp1.servage.net"; 
    $smtp_info["port"] = "25"; 
    $smtp_info["auth"] = true; 
    $smtp_info["username"] = "xxx@auto-sal.es"; 
    $smtp_info["password"] = "xxx"; 

    // Creating the PEAR mail object :
    $mail_obj =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtp_info); 

    $headers = '';
    $headers .= "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-to: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Message-ID: <" . md5(uniqid(time())) . "@" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ">\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Date: " . date('r', time()) . "\n";

    $mail_sent = $mail_obj->send($to,$subject,$body,$headers);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail_sent)) { print($mail_sent->getMessage());}
```

But i get the following error;

> Fatal error: Class 'Mail' not found in
>   /mounted-storage/hoxxx/xxx01/xx/auto-sal.es/functions.php
>   on line 17

However, My host does have those modules installed https://www.servage.net/wiki/List_of_PEAR_modules

Can anyone please advise.

Comment: Does your code have a require statement? I would have thought that error would be generated by one but that may be because of my lack of understanding of PEAR. I've heard Swift Mailer is better and it's what I've used before.

Comment: Yeah it does have require Mail.php, i have given up on this lol, i am using the normal mail() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to try to fix the current library then its probably an issue for your hosting provider as only they will know the structure of their storage system.

Another option for you may be to use [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) you can just upload the library and then include it in each page  you want to use. The website has good documentation and from experience Swift Mailer can do the SMTP you wish to do.